# git: Tracking massive repo consisting of thousands of small files only

Tags: git, github

Here is the situation. I have a project which needs to read small png files (around 20KB or 40KB each) from specific folders in the directory tree. Each folder however consists of thousands of such png images (around 70000 or 80000) hence each folder is about 400-500MB in size. To make things worse the project needs access to 28 such folders, so the whole thing is going to be pretty big (without however any single file being really massive, if that matters anyway...).

What is the recommended way/best practices for these cases please? The png image files are not going to change/edited for the whole life of the project.

I was thinking to start tracking one folder each time with git, then push the folder to github and once pushed to remove a big part from tracking (and from .git, so that this hidden folder remains very light). Then keep a note somewhere on github that anyone downloading the repo should get these files manually since they are untracked.

Is this possible please (and how?), are there any other ways to deal with the problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you add them to the repository they become part of the history for the repository. Even if you subsequently delete them from the working folder and commit that deletion, they are part of previous commits, so anyone cloning the repository would still need to download all those files.

Comment: If the files never change, and none are added or deleted, instead you should create an archive or something similar of all the files besides the git repository and create a script that downloads them

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. I dont want to delete the files from the filesystem or remove them from github. What I was thinking is to untrack them and clean the .git. Also the app runs on the browser, it is served/published by github and needs these png. They cant be zipped and sit aside somewhere

Comment: Have you looked at https://git-lfs.github.com/?

Comment: @cmbuckley, I did have a go, after seeing your note, but it hangs for ever on git add. Probably because it is designed for big single files, not big volumes of small ones. Thanks in any case

Comment: I've a feeling it could be taking ages to copy the files into the `.git/lfs` directory, as there is I/O overhead per file. Still, I wouldn't expect `git add` to take such a long time; it's `git push` where I'd expect the time, uploading 500MB to LFS storage.

Comment: @cmbuckley, yes maybe you are right. I might try doing it in batches, adding/commiting/pushing a few files in countless loops. Once you install git-lfs, and you start tracking an extension (png in this case) then this is not specific to that repo only, right? I mean if I do a new repo, and it happens to commit a png, then this file is going to be tracked by git-lfs not git, right? I also havent understood how to download the pngs (instead of the pointers) when you clone/download an git-lfs repo. Thanks again!

Comment: The changes are per-repository, so doing `git lfs track "*.png"` should only affect that repo, not other repos! Other collaborators will also need to install git-lfs to work with the files (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/collaboration-with-git-large-file-storage/)). Also check out [GitHub's storage/bandwidth quotas](https://help.github.com/articles/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage/).